# Permutation with subset

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have 20 different resources ($n=20$) distributed equally to 4 different places so that each place has 5 resources. How many combinationes are there (i.e. how many permutations are there, without considering order within or outside a place)?

My goal is to find good or bad behavior between resources by swapping different resources from place to place. So a resource is different to each other, but every place is the same.

Is $\frac{20!}{ (5!)^4 \times 4!}$ a correct solution? I have divided with $5!$ for each place to ignore ordering within a place and divided with $4!$ to eliminate the order outside a place.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: As I understand the problem, what matters here is which resources are in the same group, so we are dividing $20$ distinct resources into four unlabeled groups of $5$, in which case your solution is correct.